# The correct way to redirect user folders to a network location

Tags: network-shares, user-folders, home-directory, mapped-drive

I run a Windows 2012 R2 server where much of my content is centralized (Photos, music, applications, shared documents, videos etc).

To point each PC to this server I change the user shell folders in the registry. I also do this for the Downloads, Temp and iNetCache folders which I move off C:\ drive SSD onto a spinner to (a). Reduce writes on the SSD and (b) stop downloads filling up the C:\ drive. (The C:\ drives are 96GB for Windows and applications and generally run at 60%-70% free). The Temp folders are handled by environment variables, but Downloads and iNetCache are shell folder registry entries.

I want to leave the C:\Users\folders intact - I don't want to "move them". That rules out the location\move method. Editing the registry allows me to leave the originals intact.

Of course, none of this works until I also map the drives, and those mapped drives are "connected". There have been issues with mapped drives being disconnected at boot up since Windows 7 was released.

I'm struggling with available drive letters. I have several partitions for local drives, I keep a couple spare for thumb drives, and I have 3 optical drives. Every PC has at least one optical drive. A Couple of PCs also have SD card readers.

The server contains a \\server\users drive. Each person has their own personal folder (Eg. \\server\users\tanya), mapped to R:\ which only they and the SysAdmin have access to. There is also a shared documents folder in \\server\users\share that all users have access to.

Users have varying levels of access to other content.

I think I'm doing it all wrong. This is the way I've done it since Windows XP.

It's also possible my methodology is causing or contributing to explorer hanging and crashing when waking from sleep, though I'm struggling to prove that.

All PCs are Windows 10 Pro and a couple of Dual boot systems with Windows 7 Ultimate. I use Group Policy extensively.

All PCs get their updates from the WSUS on the 2012 R2 server. I also run IIS, MySQL and Cold fusion on the server. We also have a PC dedicated to run Kodi with MySQL, but as Kodi requires a very old version of MySQL I cannot run it on the main server. Each PC runs Macrium, as does the server, to a USB connected HDD on the server for backups, which is a mapped drive on each PC.

SMB 1.0 is not used and Netbios Over TCP is enabled on all PCs. I do not use active directory, nor do I want to.

So - what is the right way to do this?

Would value your thoughts and suggestions

thank you.

Comment: When could we talk about - It's also possible my methodology is causing or contributing to explorer hanging and crashing when waking from sleep, though I'm struggling to prove that. - ?  View my profile for contact info.